# Trying to read/write memory in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm a programmer novice, I want to write some code to change the values in the store function in the windows calculator.
I used Cheat engine to grab the address of the value store. I found this code online and copied it, but it won't write to the address.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int newValue = 500;  //value to be written

HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, "Calculator");

if (hWnd == 0){
    cerr << "Cannot find window." << endl;
}
else {
    DWORD pId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pId);
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pId);

    if (!hProc) {
        cerr << "Cannot open process." << endl;
    }
    else {
        int isSucessful = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)0xD2FD6EAD0C, &newValue, (DWORD)sizeof(newValue), NULL);

        if (isSucessful > 0) {
            clog << "Process memory written" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cerr << "Cannot write process memory" << endl;
        }

        CloseHandle(hProc);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

When I execute it I get reply "cannot write process memory"
is this any particular flaws in this code? I wrote it exactly as I read it from the dude who executed it in this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0zPwg4iUDk.

Comment: You could use GetLastError to get more information what might went wrong: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/479880/GetLastError-as-std-string

Comment: You're a programming novice and you're trying to hack calc.exe from another process (don't OS's exist to stop you from doing that? imagine the security risks! Good grief!!!) and wondering why it doesn't work?

Comment: @StefanFalk ... and a decent debugger of course!

Comment: I highly recommend you print out the starting address of the Calc's process memory.  This will help you verify that the address 0xD2FD6EAD06 is within boundaries.  By the way, there is no guarantee the memory nor execution addresses will the same for an executable each invocation;  they may differ.

Comment: A better method is to use *offsets*.  Find the relative offset of the memory location you want to modify.  Add this offset to the Process Memory of the Calc program.  That will get you closer than your present method.

Comment: @Thomas: What is *"the Process Memory of Calc"* and how do you add an offset to it?

Comment: The memory address you get may be different if ASLR is enabled: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: @IInspectable:  The *Calc* refers to the *Calculator* program.  The *Process Memory* refers to the memory area of a running program or *process*.  So *the Process Memory of Calc* is the {starting} address of the Calculator program's memory area.  You add an offset by getting the pointer and adding an offset or number to the pointer.

Comment: @Thomas: There is no such thing as the *"{starting} address of a program's memory area"*. There are several base addresses of loaded modules, and at least one heap. So.... which address should one pick to add some offset to it?